# How i can send HTTP POST directly in java

Tags: web-services, http, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to send an HTTP POST request with payload morethan 255 to URL as shown

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8080/Application_name
```

, it should hit a Servlet directly , For that I configured web.xml as shown below.

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
   <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>Servlet</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>Servlet_INTERFACE</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.app.package1.Servlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet_INTERFACE</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When i tried , all request is going as GET only. When i tried

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8080/Application_name/Servlet
```

then its working fine

1. is it possible?
2. If yes , How can i do it?
3. Is Aliasing is a Solution

Comment: If a GET is always being used, the problem is most likely with your client. Could you update the question with your http client code?

Comment: What container are you using (this used to be a bug with tomcat)? Did you try adding the trailing slash in the welcome file definition: */Servlet*?

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet handles requests in 2 methods only one of them depending of the request type:

doGet
doPost

you can write something like this in your servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException 
{       
 ......GET CODE.....
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException 
{       
......POST CODE.....
}
```